# How to validate a service object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, service

I have this service class, and I need to validate the following properties `key` and `url` that actually live on a different model.

```
    class MobileInstallationService
      class << self
        def connected?(id)
          # do something to @mi
        end

        def track_usage?(id)
          # do something to @mi
        end

        private

        def load_installation(id)
          @mi = Installation.find id
        end
      end
    end
```

Installations can be of different types, that's why I have a model `Installation` that keeps tracks of them, i.e. all the CRUD operations, and each installation would have `properties` hstore on it, which would vary greatly.

```
class Installation

  belongs_to :user
  validates user, presence: true

end
```

Here's the example of that Installation object with two properties I need to validate:

```
=> #<Installation id: 25, user_id: 8, created_at: "2021-07-22 22:35:10", updated_at: "2021-07-22 22:35:25", user_id: 16, properties: {"key"=>"123", "url"=>"www.google.com"}>
```

However, different types of installations have very little in common in terms of particular methods used on them (for example, this one has `connected?` method, but others don't).
That's why I don't want to couple the parent controller that performs all the CRUD do validate there, for example:

```
class InstallationController < SomeController
  before_action :load_installation

  def show
  end

  def update
      # could validate here but this class doesn't need to know about specific types
      # of installation - so I don't want to introduce coupling
      @installation.update(properties: params[:properties])
    end
  end

  private
    def load_installation
      @installation = Installation.find(id)
    end
end
```

And the form that I've built requires an instance of the main Installation class, i.e. `@installation` so ideally I need to do something on the `submit` action

```
= form_for @installation, url: installation_path(@installation.id), method: :put do |f|

  %button {type: "submit"} SAVE
    = fields_for :settings do |s|
      = s.text_field :key
      = s.text_field :url
```

Comment: Have you tried using single table inheritance?

Comment: Many years ago I built a multi-table inheritance gem for ruby.  I highly doubt it would work today since I haven't maintained it though. :) https://github.com/mhuggins/multiple_table_inheritance